# Chromecast and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, chromecast, google-cast

I want to use Google Cast from Swift.

Scanning for devices is working and it finds one Chromecast device.

```
var scanner = GCKDeviceScanner()
scanner.addListener(self)
scanner.startScan()

func deviceDidComeOnline(device: GCKDevice!) {
    println("device found: - \(device.friendlyName)");
}
```

this displays: `device found: - MyChrome`

To connect to the device I use:

```
        var cpm = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["CFBundleIdentifier"] as? NSString
        var dm = GCKDeviceManager(device: scanner.devices[0] as GCKDevice, clientPackageName: cpm)

        dm.delegate = self
        dm.connect()
```

but it never comes in here:

```
func deviceManagerDidConnect(deviceManager: GCKDeviceManager!) {
    println("device connected")
    //TODO
}  

func deviceManager(deviceManager: GCKDeviceManager!, didFailToConnectWithError error: NSError!) {
    println(error)
}
```

What am I missing?

---

UPDATE: question mentioned by @feri was helpful.

I was using this inside the button action:

```
var dm = GCKDeviceManager(device: scanner.devices[0] as GCKDevice, clientPackageName: cpm)
```

After declaring it as property of the class everything is working:

```
class MyController: ... {
  var dm : GCKDeviceManager!
  ...

  func xxxx() {}
  func yyy() {}
}
```

Comment: I have encountered the same kind of problems. I've recently ask a question here on Stackoverflow and it got answered. Maybe my code can help you a bit. Here is the link to my post.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27401967/init-with-chromecast-in-swift

Comment: Thanks, your post helped! I updated the question. I was declaring the `GCKDeviceManager` inside my button action. Should have declared it as property of the class. It's working now, I can launch my custom receiver app on the Chromecast and send and receive messages.

Comment: No problem happy to help! Can you help me with "**keeping**" the connection with a Chromecast I can make an connection, but it's saying it's connected. But it never is.. I have no idea what to do.. You can see my post here for more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27423261/connecting-disconnecting-to-from-an-chromecast-device-with-swift

Comment: Are you running the app in the simulator or on a real device? Testing in the simulator almost always gives me `no devices found` only rarely it finds a device when running in the simulator. On a real device I don't have that problem, but in this application I have a listview of videos where I always do a connect to the `GCKDeviceManager` first to the 1st device found and send a message to a custom receiver that plays a youtube video. But I only have 1 week experience with both xcode and swift. Never used ios/objective-c before, it's all new to me.

Comment: Also for real testing I need to unplug the cable to my Ipad and restart the app otherwise I also have problems finding and connecting to a Chromecast.