# Connecting/disconnecting to/from an Chromecast Device with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, chromecast

I recently started to develop and Chromecast application with Apple new language Swift.
But I'm stuck at making an connection with the Chromecast device. What it does so far that It can see an Chromecast on the network. After that there will appear an AlertController(an AlertController is the same as an ActionSheet) The reason why I use AlertController is, because ActionSheet is deprecated by Apple. At first I thought it would be the ActionSheet thats making it not work. After that I've tried allot of different version of ActionController/ActionSheet, but no luck so far.. As an reference for creating this in Swift
I used Google Cast Example apps what is in Objective C.
https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-ios

--**UPDATE**--

After the Alertcontroller popup I click an device it's then connecting and succeeds. When I'm trying to disconnect it's giving me an exception error "**unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**". I'm getting this error on this line of code.

```
self.mediaInformation.metadata.stringForKey(kGCKMetadataKeyTitle)
```

So basically it's saying the mediaInformation = nil,

```
self.mediaInformation.metadata.stringForKey(kGCKMetadataKeyTitle!)
```

so I thought lets make it optional, but that didn't work. Does anyone know why it's not working?

```
func chooseDevice() {
    if selectedDevice == nil {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Choose an device..", message: "Click on your chromecast!", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        for device in deviceScanner.devices {
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: device.friendlyName, style: .Default, handler: { alertAction in
                self.selectedDevice = device as GCKDevice
                self.connectToDevice()
            }))
        }

        let addCancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: { alertAction in
            alertController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        })

        // Add action to the controller
        alertController.addAction(addCancelAction)

        // Finaly present the action controller
        presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        updateButtonStates()

        var mediaTitle = GCKMediaInformation()
        mediaTitle.metadata.stringForKey(self.textFieldUrl.text)

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Casting to: \(selectedDevice.friendlyName)", message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        let addDisconnectingAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Disconnect device", style: .Destructive, handler: { alertAction in
            println("De waarde van mediaInformation is: \(self.mediaInformation)")
            if self.mediaInformation != nil {
                (self.mediaInformation != nil ? 1 : 0)
                alertController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                println("the else UIAlertController")
            }
        })

        let addCancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: { alertAction in
            println("De waarde van mediaInformation is: \(self.mediaInformation)")
            if self.mediaInformation != nil {
                (self.mediaInformation != nil ? 2 : 1)
                alertController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                println("else uiactionsheet")
            }
        })

        alertController.addAction(addDisconnectingAction)
        alertController.addAction(addCancelAction)

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

This is how I make an connection with the Chromecast. It could be something wrong in `connectToDevice()` or in `deviceManagerDidConnect()`? The weard thing is that I never get the message "Connected" in `deviceManagerDidConnect()`

```
func connectToDevice() {
    if selectedDevice != nil {
        var info = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String
        deviceManager = GCKDeviceManager(device: selectedDevice, clientPackageName: info)

        NSLog("De waarde van info: \(info)")
        NSLog("De waarde van deviceManager in connectToDevice() is: \(deviceManager)")

        deviceManager = GCKDeviceManager(device: deviceScanner.devices[0] as GCKDevice, clientPackageName: info)
        deviceManager.delegate = self
        deviceManager.connect()
    }
}

    func deviceManagerDidConnect(deviceManager: GCKDeviceManager!) {
        NSLog("Connected!")

        updateButtonStates()

        deviceManager.launchApplication(kReceiverAppID)
}
```

Comment: Struggling with this, could you please post demo code on github ? I see no proper example to share app screen (i don't need to play video). Please..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do something in the handler for the UIAlertAction to set self.selectedDevice

eg

```
    for selectedDevice in self.deviceScanner.devices {
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: selectedDevice.friendlyName, style: .Default, handler: { action in
            self.selectedDevice = device
            self.connectToDevice()
        }))
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but thats not it :(

Comment: You have changed the question now so my answer bears no relation to how the question now reads.

Comment: I changed the question after your answer.

Comment: Indeed you did and I cannot see any reason why you wouldn't just ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Media title will be nil if you are not casting any media so use it in this way:
*Declaration:*

```
var mediaInformation : GCKMediaInformation?
```

*Usage:*

```
let mediaTitle = self.mediaInformation?.metadata.stringForKey(kGCKMetadataKeyTitle)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But its still nill, so that means I cannot disconnected from an connected Chromecast device.

Comment: Means you still getting error and app is crashing? Because now even if its nil it will not throw any error because it is optional

Comment: Thank you for your comment. No It's not crashing anymore. What I meant is that the code continues and then the "UIAlertController" gets called and when I press device disconnect in the UIAlertController nothing happens. It is not disconnecting. It stays connected in some kind of weird way. Maybe It's because the MediaTitle is still nil? Or is the connected device not properly connected? Honestly I don't know where to look anymore.. I'm lost :(

Comment: Then Its not because of media title will explain more later